# External Javascript files not loading when published to IIS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, localhost

The javascripts works fine on my iis developmental server as well as when I try to access the website using http://localhost:8080

However, it does not load when I replace localhost with my actual ip address so for example it would be http://10.1.65.48:8080 instead of http://localhost:8080

I have tried to replace all my URLs using @Url.Content and it still does not work for some reason

Below are all the external javascript files I tried to load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery.min.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/bootstrap.min.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery.stellar.min.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/owl.carousel.min.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/popper.min.js")" defer></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/aos.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery.timepicker.min.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/scrollax.min.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/google-map.js")" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/main.js")" defer></script>
```

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: I think it is v5.2.4

Comment: try `src="/js/main.js"` instead

Comment: still the same result

Comment: I suggest you could firstly try to clear the cache for your browser and try to check the IIS url rewrite rule to make sure there are no rule which will affect the  http://10.1.65.48 ip address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your local IIS site bindings.  Right click on the top level site (in my case, it's Default Web Site) and click on Edit Bindings.  Make sure the binding for port 8080 has either the IP address you're using selected or is set to (All Unassigned) and ensure no host name is supplied.  When I supplied a host name in my site, it stopped accepting the IP address as a URL, so if I had to guess, that is probably your issue.

Comment: It didn't work as I have tried setting it to my IP address as well as to All Unassigned. However, when I created a new site and set the port number to 9090 it worked for some reason.

Comment: Is there something special about the port number 8080 that I am not aware of?

Comment: @ByronicHero Nope -- I just used it since it's the one you're using.